# Delaying LINQ to SQL Select Query Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site that uses LINQ to SQL.

In my search method that has some required and some optional parameters, I want to **build a LINQ query while testing for the existence of those optional parameters**.

---

Here's what I'm currently thinking:

```
using(var db = new DBDataContext())
        {
            IQueryable<Listing> query = null;

            //Handle required parameter
            query = db.Listings.Where(l => l.Lat >= form.bounds.extent1.latitude && l.Lat <= form.bounds.extent2.latitude);

            //Handle optional parameter
            if (numStars != null)
                query = query.Where(l => l.Stars == (int)numStars);

            //Other parameters...

            //Execute query (does this happen here?)
            var result = query.ToList();

            //Process query...
```

---

Will this implementation **"bundle" the `where` clauses and then execute the bundled query**? If not, how should I implement this feature?

Also, is there anything else that I can improve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the query will only be executed once `ToList()` is called. If you follow this pattern and are using anonymous types, be aware of `OrderBy()` returning `IOrderedQueryable` instead of `IQueryable`.

Be aware that you are able to just iterate over the `IQueryable`, you don't have to call `ToList` to access the data.